# Process to test and add new wireless network configuration through wpa_cli

Tags: linux, embedded, wifi, wpa

I am trying to implement a code which is using wpa_cli & iw to configure/add/remove/test new network entry to my wpa conf.

To add a new network my process is :

**wpa_cli list_network**

my new entry already exist ?  yes -> remove it

**wpa_cli add_network**
-> create entry empty entry with id 42

**wpa_cli set_network 42 ssid '"tutu"'**

**wpa_cli set_network 42 psk '"mypassword"'**

**wpa_cli enable 42**

**wpa_cli save_config**

-> update wpa_conf file with new entry

**wpa_cli select_network 42**

-> use this command to test connexion with only this network entry check every second during 10 seconds, iw dev wlan0 link result to check that ssid/psk info are good.

I am not very sure about this process. Moreover, it seems that there is a cache somewhere. If I replace an existing entry  but with fake psk, I am always connected to this entry.

example :

I have a wireless network setup like this :
ssid : tutu
password : mypassword

I add the configuration tutu/mypassword thanks to my process. After the select_network, the iw link show "Connected". Great.

Now I add the configuration tutu/badpassword with the same process. The older configuration is removed. The select_network and iw link always success even if the new password is wrong...

EDIT :

I found some good information here to validate my process : http://rtl8192cu.googlecode.com/hg-history/bdd3a2265bdd6a92f24cef3d52fa594b2844c9c1/document/wpa_cli_with_wpa_supplicant.pdf

But I have always some failed. I run endurance test en wifi connection. On 100 tests with good ssid/psk, 99 success, 1 failed.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry Ross. I add an example to explain why my process seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when conf changed or config saved, use

**wpa_cli reconfigure**

then wpa-supplicant will re-read its configuration file